# Is it possible to make looped Movieclip clickable and Session data at the same time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to AS3, and i am trying to achieve the following situation.

First i receive the JSON data,sort them and put them into boxes . Each box has its set of data, e.g.Box1 (Name1,Location1,Zip1), Box2(Name2,Location2,Zip2) so on. 
Boxes are put into another AS file for display, and will be put into a viewport slider. 
Trying to make the boxes clickable, and when a box is clicked, it will go to next page and display the details of that specific "Listing".

1st thing is, how to make the movieclip box clickable when it is sitting inside another as file.

2nd thing is, how to pull the data from that box when it is clicked, as it is generated by the looped JSON data. (As i need to use the ID from the listing to parse it to the php to pull the details and display the full detail in the next as file.

Thanks for your time!

AS file where the boxes are generated.

```
package  com.clark
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {


        public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1>) 
        {
            super();

                for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) 
            {


                trace(test[j].nobed);
                trace(test[j].zip);
                trace(test[j].Location);
                trace(test[j].price);

        }
var len:int = test ? test.length : 0;

     listings = new Vector.<Listing8>(len, true);
            var currentY:int = 100;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing2 = new Listing2();

                Bolder.x=20;

                var bf:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

                bf3.width = 100;
                bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                bf.width = 100;
                bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf1.width = 100;
                bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.width = 100;
                bf1.y= bf.height+5;


                bf.text = test[k].nobed;
                bf1.text = test[k].zip;
                bf2.text = test[k].Location;
                bf3.text = test[k].price;

                bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.2
                Bolder.addChild(bf);
                Bolder.addChild(bf1);
                Bolder.addChild(bf2);
                Bolder.addChild(bf3);
                Bolder.properties = test[k].nobed;
            Bolder.properties = test[k].zip;

                // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
            Bolder.y = currentY;




                addChild(Bolder);
                 Bolder.mouseChildren = false;    // ignore children mouseEvents
            Bolder.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
            Bolder.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
            Bolder.buttonMode = true; 
                 listings[k] = Bolder;
                currentY += Bolder.height + 10;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

AS file where the VectTest file sits

```
package com.clark

{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;




       public class sresultnologin extends MovieClip {

public var s1:Searchreult = new Searchreult ();

               public function sresultnologin(){
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);
         function onadded (event:Event):void{


            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);
         }

var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(new Vector.<searchVO1>);
                 addChild (s3);


            s1.SRhome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTol);
            s1.ARsearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGosearch);


     if( s3.listings.length > 0 )
        {
            // get the first listing in the listing array
            var newListing:Listing8 = s3.listings[0];
            newListing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscener);
        }
        else
        {                    
//
        }
                       }
               // private methods

        private function fl_ClickToGoTol(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:Account = new Account ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);

        }

        private function fl_ClickToGosearch(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:searchVO1 = new searchVO1 ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);


       }

}
}
```

Edit(Added in SearchVectorTest)

```
var len:int = test ? test.length : 0;

         listings = new Vector.<Listing8>(len, true);
```

Edit(Added in sresultnologin)

```
if( s3.listings.length > 0 )
        {
            // get the first listing in the listing array
            var newListing:Listing8 = s3.listings[0];
            newListing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscener);
        }
        else
        {

//

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### One

The "other as file" (a class) must be instantiated, and (as a [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html)) must be added to the stage for it to become visible.

Consider the following stage layout:

```
root:MainTimeline ¬
    0: background:Shape
    1: listingWindow:Slider
```

And the `sresultnologin` (when instantiated) looks like this:

```
this:sresultnologin ¬
    0: s3:SearchVectorTest ¬
        0: Bolder:Listing2 ¬
            0: bf:TextField
            1: bf1:TextField
            2: bf2:TextField
            3: bf3:TextField
    1: s1:Searchreult
```

All you need to do is addChild(sresultnologin) to the stage (or your Slider), and those child elements will appear.

**To make it clickable**, simply attach the listener to your object via [*`object`*`.addEventListener("mouseUp", listener)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29).  This can be done at any point: in the constructor of `SearchVectorTest`, or `sresultnologin`, or after it's been added to the stage when your "box is clicked" and the new listing appears.  If you wanted to do that from the document code, it might look like this:

```
var newListing:Listing2 = listingWindow.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0);
newListing.addEventListener("mouseUp", doStuff);
```

However, that's wholly dependent on DisplayList indexes (which could change wildly).  A better solution may be to name these items and use [`getChildByName("string")`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29) instead.  That too, however, could be perilous if you have non-unique names for each object.  Consequently, if you're adding these new listings from inside one of your classes (such as `sresultnologin`), you could simply provide a property on the class which points to the current listing, and reference that from document code.

### Two

JSON data is no different from any other object structure in AS3.  If you want, you could store it as a property of the class, and reference the variable at the appointed time. If you want to store data specific to a particular listing on the particular object which represents it, try adding to `Bolder` in `SearchVectorTest` the following:

```
Bolder.properties = test[k];
```

---

### Edit:

Remember that the variable name is not the same as the name property on an object. In other words...

```
var Bolder:Listing2 = new Listing2(); // variable is Bolder, of type Listing2
Bolder.name = "foo" // the name property on Bolder is now "foo"

getChildByName("Bolder") // this should fail since there is no object with that name
getChildByName("foo") // works.
```

This really isn't complicated as long as you're aware of the differences.  [Please run the script I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629165/how-to-link-functionality-from-class-file-to-documentclass-and-to-movieclips-in) (under *"Pathing to Objects"*) which shows you the hierarchy of your stage.  After you have the output, it should be self-explanatory what pathing you need to use to reference your variables.

Comment: Just wondering why in the var newListing:Listing2=listingWindow.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0); has the getChildAt(0) behind them? Sorry for the noob question

Comment: You're digging through a hierarchy (like folders).  `getChildAt(0)` simply fetches the first element in that container.  You can string together these statements because at each step, the function request resolves into the object you requested, which you can then run the same command on to get the next child element.  `listingWindow.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0)` is effectively the same as `listingWindow.sresultnologin.s3.Bolder`.  Because these objects are dynamically created, we can't use that dot.notation to path to it, and must use built-in methods to fetch by index or name.

Comment: Cos i am having error from the line var newListing:Listing2 = listingWindow.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0); i want to make the Bolder(which is the boxes) clickable so i assume i do,Bolder.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0); But then it says Access of Undefined Property. Not very sure why. I added that in sresultnologin.as

Comment: I added Bolder as public var Movieclip, that error seems to have disappeared, but it is still giving me an error for Listing2 saying type was not found.

Comment: Hi, i just saw the edits, I edited my answer before that, to give Bolder name as listing[k], i added that in the answer above, i guess it is the same as your edit?